# Angular - capacitor Angular http request doesn't work on android build

Tags: angular, http, capacitor

On desktop or mobile in browser (firefox) calling my backend endpoint returns the result I'd like (json object), however on capacitor android build I get an html response that is auto generated by capacitor. There is a comment in the html:

```
/**
         * API is not implemented.
         *
         * This usually means the API can't be used because it is not implemented for
         * the current platform.
         */
```

I've tried seraching for the error, but I couldn't find any results except, that capacitor has an http plugin, but I wouldn't like to rewrite my code changing all angular http to capacitor http. Are there any other solutions for this issue?
Package versions:

- angular/core: 15.2.0
- capacitor/android: 4.7.0
- capacitor/angular:2.0.3
- capacitor/core: latest
- capacitor/ios: 4.7.0

Http request:

```
function(id: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`/api/endpoint/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: For native apps you should consider a different HttpClient: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http

Comment: @WSD I've had an older angular capacitor app, that used angular's httpclient and worked fine.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're having trouble with? Specifically, the HTTP request and its usage. I have several Angular + Cap or even Ionic + cap/cordova applications and I've never encountered this issue. So its  interesting for me and maybe i can help.

Comment: @DanielVágner I've update the post with the HTTP request.
I've also just realized that angular development build uses localhost as start of the url which could be an issue since I'm using 2 different devices. I'm currently looking up, how can I use my backend's ip instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont include your base url. So it will indeed set default to the current domain, something like http://localhost/api/endpoint/${id} during local development.

```
function(id: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`/api/endpoint/${id}`);
}
```

I would create environment.ts or some config.json

and add one for dev and prod

```
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_base_url: 'http://localhost:3000' // your api url
};
```

after that you could use it like this.

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

...

function(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.api_base_url}/api/endpoint/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: I've created 2 environtment files and using variables, however in development build it attaches the whole url after localhost/ (localhost/{my server ip address}/api...). Is it possible to remove the localhost starting when testing in development build environment?

Comment: Found the solution, only the ip address as the value in the environtment file wasn't enough. Had to add http://